# Sort a data table using an external list

Tags: r

As the title said, I have in one hand a data table with rows and columns.
The header of this table contains sample names (e.g: A B C D E F G ) and the table contains thousands of rows.

In the other hand, I have a list (factor) of groups (e.g: group3, group2, group3, group1, group2, group3, group1, group3) with 3 factors, as the group of the list corresponds to the sample of the table's header :

A is in group3
B is in group2
C is in group3
D is in group1
and so on...

What I saw, is to sort tables using a variable inside the table, but I would like to sort the table using the list, without including the list in the table.

At the end, I would like to have the table columns sorted as :
D G B E A C F G

The orden of the sample names is not so important (so we could even have for example : G D B E A F G C, it doesn't matter), what is indeed important is to have sample names sorted as their corresponding groups are sorted :
group1 group1 group2 group2 group3 group3 group3 group3

Of course, the list have to be sorted in the same way to avoid to loose the correspondance between groups and sample names...

Anyone have an idea ?
Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Do you actually have a `data.table` or do you mean `data.frame`?

Comment: As I use read.table(), I guess this is a data.table, isn't it ?

Comment: No, it's a `data.frame`. There is a big difference. It's unfortunate the function names don't quite match up.

Comment: Oh I see now. Data.table come from a package. I didn't even think about it as I was thinking that tables come from read.table. I took a look, and that indeed different. Well I learnt a lot of things, thanks MrFlick !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to have to create sample data since you did not provide any

```
#sample data
dd <- data.frame(A=1, B=2, C=3, D=4, E=5, F=6, G=7, H=8)
groups <- factor(c("group3","group2","group3","group1",
    "group2","group3","group1","group3"))
```

Then you can rearrage the data.frame and the groups with

```
dd <- dd[, order(groups)]
groups <- groups[order(groups)]

#   D G B E A C F H
# 1 4 7 2 5 1 3 6 8
```

Comment: Thank you it seems to work! Sorry for the data, I have a terrible headache and didn't think about it...